# Sum vs XOR menas x+a=x^a ,

Tags: java, performance, math, bit-manipulation

Given an integer, 0<= x <=a , find each such that:
x+a=x^a ,
where denotes the bit wise XOR operator. Then print an integer denoting the total number of x's satisfying the criteria above.
for example a=5 then x=0,2
a+x=a^x;
I tried to solve this way. Is there any other way to reduce time complexity.

```
 `public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    long n = in.nextLong();
    int cnt=0;
    for(long i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
        long m=i^n;
        if(n+i==m)
            cnt++;
    }
    System.out.println(cnt);
}`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n` can have any bit not set in `a` and this formula will hold.

This means the number of bits to permutate will be 32 minus the number of bits set in `a` i.e. `Integer.bitCount`

```
long cnt = 1L << (32 - Integer.bitCount(a));
```

Note if `a` has 0 or 1 bit set, the number of solutions is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 1):

This solution could help you.
**numberOfLeadingZeros** give how many zeros before last set bit from left,
and **bitCount** give how many bits set for value **a**.

```
long count = 1L<<(64-Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(a) - Long.bitCount(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

**x+a=x^a**

if x=5 and (a=0 or a=2) only two value satisfy this condition **x+a=x^a**

```
Logic:- **To check number of zero bit**.
```

for example x=10, in binary representation of x=1010. 
Algorithm:

1. 1010 & 1== 0000 so count=1 and 1010 >>1=101
2. 101 & 1 !=0 so count will remain same 101>>1=10
3. 10 & 1==00 so count = 2 and 10>>1=1
4. 1 & 1 !=0 so again count remain same and 1>>1=0 (exit).
5. answer will 2 to power count means 4.

   `int xor(int x)
       { 
         int count=0;
         while((x!=0)
          {
              if((x&1)==0)

              count++;
              x=x>>1;
           }

         return 1<<count;
        }`

**this loop will execute only number of bits available. and it will reduce time complexity**

Comment: If `x=5`, you could also have `a=8`.  You're assuming `a` can't have more bits available than `x`.  Otherwise, this is equivalent to the existing answer.  (Also, should `n$1` be `n&1`?  And why not just `return 1<<count`?)

Comment: Thanks @Teepeemm yes it will  **(n&1)** and according to Question value of **a** should be less or equal to **n** .  you can also return **1<<count**